# Are there any advantages or specific cases where we should prefer using Binary search tree rather than AVL tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Are there any advantages or specific cases where we should prefer using Binary search tree rather than AVL tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the time complexity of `lookup/insert/remove` operations, then BST is good enough. It's easier to implement and requires less space. However, in the worst case, its performance is O(n) - imagine adding only increasing or decreasing elements to your BST.

On the other hand, if you do care about the performance, then you may use an AVL tree because it is a self-balancing BST - its height is guaranteed to be ~ log(n), where n is a number of nodes in the tree. That's why lookup `lookup/insert/remove` operations are logarithmic. However, an AVL tree requires more space (each node needs to hold its `height`), and additional logic to re-balance the tree if such property gets violated.